# Does Debian 12 running on a Dell XPS 15 9520 support "deep" suspend mode?

Tags: debian, suspend, sleep

I have checked the file **/sys/power/mem_sleep** and it only has the value **[s2idle]**, I didn't see the option **deep**, but maybe is missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.